# Is there a way to create an instance of a Class<T> which takes in Class as a parameter in constructor passing generics

Tags: java

```
class JsonSerializer<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    public JsonSerializer(Class<T> type){
         this.type = type;
    }
}
Serializer<Map<String, byte[]>> serializer = new JsonSerializer<Map<String, byte[]>>(Map<String, byte[]>.class)
```

for above compiler throws an error and hence I end up casting later to `Map<String,byte[]>`.

Comment: Something like this should work: `new JsonSerializer<Map<String, byte[]>>((Class<Map<String, byte[]>>) (Class) Map.class)`

Comment: Hi, the code above will never compile without a `type` field and orphaned code outside a `class` declaration Could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a clear description of your issue?

Comment: What are you going to end up doing with `type` inside your class? What methods do you need to invoke on it, or where do you pass it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `Class` objects because you can't obtain a `Class<Map<String, byte[]>>`, only a `Class<Map>`.

But you can do this if you use e.g. a `Supplier<T>` instead:

```
class JsonSerializer<T> {
    public JsonSerializer(Supplier<T> typeSupplier){
         this.typeSupplier = typeSupplier;

         // When you need an instance of `T`:
         T instance = typeSupplier.get();
    }
}

Serializer<Map<String, byte[]>> serializer = new JsonSerializer<>(HashMap::new);
```

or, if you don't actually need to create a new instance of `T`, but instead can use some sort of "prototype" object:

```
class JsonSerializer<T> {
    public JsonSerializer(T instance){
         this.instance = instance;
    }
}

Serializer<Map<String, byte[]>> serializer = new JsonSerializer<>(ImmutableMap.of());
```

Comment: You actually can do this with 2 casts, first an upcast and then a down cast. See my answer to the question

Comment: @user3528269 to hoots with type safety, eh?

Comment: it's not less type safe than your solution

Comment: @user3528269 are you sure about that?

Comment: @user3528269 isn't it same as saying new JS<Map<String, byte[]>>((Class) Map.class);

Comment: @AndyTurner he btw also asked for a class object and not an actual instance of it

Comment: @AndyTurner and since we're doing the up and down cast at the same place this shouldn't fail. If you try this also with other type parameters outside of the constructor, the code will not compile

Comment: @user3528269 "he btw also asked for a class object" is an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu yours emits 2 warnings, raw usage and unchecked cast (at least in intellij)

Comment: @user3528269 Once you are down to class, the additional (Class<Map<String, byte[]>>) is just superficial cast to rid the warning, isn't it? I see a warning message for each variation of the suggestions discussed here.

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu to get rid of the raw usage warning yes

Comment: @AndyTurner your solution also works but since I just need the type to pass further to another method call, I do not have to create an instance. Thanks.